# Paymill: Creating transactions

Tags: api, paymill

Until few days ago i used this url to create a transaction:

https://api.paymill.de/v2/transactions?token=XXXX&amount=XXXX&currency=EUR&client=client_XXXX

And now i am getting a error:

Return Message

> Error calling API: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

I think is something related with the data format.

Answer (score 0):

you have to send this as a POST request to the Paymill API.  See examples at: https://www.paymill.com/de-de/dokumentation/referenz/api-referenz/#create-new-transaction-with

Also check if your credentials (Private API Key) is valid.

Matthias